# Python executable error (created using cxfreeze and scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, cx-freeze

I'm using python version 3.4.3, cxfreeze version 4.3.4 and a fresh install of scipy.

> Creating an executable of my script works fine but attempting to run
>   it gives the error:   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 95, in
>   from . import lsoda as _lsoda
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'lsoda'.

Navigating to that folder shows no lsoda python file, only `lsoda.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: cx_Freeze has [problems freezing scipy](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/43/import-errors-when-using-cx_freeze-with).